# Error "python setup.py egg_info" while installing scikit-learn using pipenv

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

I have been getting following error while installing sklearn using pipenv. I have tried various suggestions including upgrading setuptools and pip. I have also tried installing my everything on different ubuntu machines. I believe this issue might be due to conflict between package versions. Would appreciate any help.

Here is the error:

```
Pipfile.lock (60e0f6) out of date, updating to (780331)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
elf.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 174, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 222, in get_legacy_dependencies
    result = reqset._prepare_file(self.finder, ireq, ignore_requires_python=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/req/req_set.py", line 644, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/req/req_set.py", line 134, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/req/req_install.py", line 435, in run_egg_info
    call_subprocess(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/utils/__init__.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(
pip9.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmp9c38a1_hbuild/scikit-learn/
```

Here is my Pipfile

```
[packages]
django = "==3.2.13"
asgiref = "==3.4.1"
autopep8 = "==1.6.0"
dj-database-url = "==0.5.0"
gunicorn = "==20.1.0"
pycodestyle = "==2.8.0"
pytz = "==2021.3"
sqlparse = "==0.4.2"
toml = "==0.10.2"
whitenoise = "==5.3.0"
django-environ = "==0.8.1"
mysqlclient = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
drf-nested-routers = "*"
celery = "*"
redis = "*"
sqlalchemy = "*"
pymupdf = "*"
django-redis = "*"
pyarrow = "*"
djoser = "*"
pillow = "*"
matplotlib = "*"
seaborn = "*"
openpyxl = "*"
django-allauth = "*"
stripe = "*"
python-magic = "*"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that sklearn isn't actually installed even though this error is being thrown? I was getting this same error, but sklearn still installed properly

Comment: That’s the thing, sklearn does end up getting installed but if I add it to pipfile, then it throws the above the error. I have spent so much time, can’t seem to solve it.

Comment: I encountered a similar error and what I had to end up doing was creating a brand new pipenv file, running `python3 -m pipenv install <library>` for every single library. The error was still thrown, but when I ran `python3 -m pipenv run python` and then ran `import <library>` it ended up working. I have no idea why, but it did